# How to make a list with a variable name?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm using the mtcars dataset for this example.

I have a function which creates a named list using a variable:

```
make_list <- function(df, variable_name) {

    a <- df %>%
        list(variable_name = .)

        return(a)
}
```

When I use this function:

```
mylist <- make_list(mtcars, "car_info")

head(mylist)
$variable_name
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

The list name is called `variable_name`, rather than `car_info`.

How do I change the function (but still use a pipe format) so that the correct name is returned?

Comment: Why do you need to still use pipe format? It doesn't seem to be achieving anything for you here.

Comment: It's part of a wider function that I'm using on my data - the example would be too complicated to post here so I simplified it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to continue using the pipe, you can use `setNames`:

```
make_list <- function(df, variable_name) {
  
    df %>%
    list%>%
    setNames(variable_name)
  
}

make_list(mtcars, "car_info")
```

Output:

```
$car_info
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

Comment: Yes, this is a better answer than mine. I'd just add that if you're doing it like this, assigning to a variable at all is unnecessary. You can just use:
`make_list <- function(df, variable_name) { df %>% list %>% setNames(variable_name) }`

Answer (score 2):

```
make_list <- function(df, variable_name) {

    a <- df %>% list
    names(a) <- variable_name

    return(a)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
make_list <- function(df, variable_name) {
  
  a <- df %>%
    list()
  names(a) <- variable_name
  
  return(a)
}

mylist <- make_list(mtcars, "car_info")
```

Output (Some rows):

```
mylist
$car_info
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

Comment: The `(variable_name = .)` here is redundant, since that name is getting removed anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`rlang` has a `list2` function that does that

```
make_list <- function(df, variable_name) {
  rlang::list2(!! variable_name := df)
}

make_list(mtcars, "car_info")

#> $car_info
#>                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

Or `tibble::lst` works the same: `make_list <- function(df, variable_name) tibble::lst(!! variable_name := df)`